# Why does word segmentation require dynamic programming?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I am referring to this problem:

> Given a dictionary, i.e., a set of strings, and a string s, design an
>   efficient algorithm that checks whether s is the concatenation of a
>   sequence of dictionary words. If such a concatenation exists, your
>   algorithm should output it.

Here's how I solved it, without using DP:

```
def getwords(s, start = 0):
  # Find a valid word as a prefix, and try to made the rest work
  for i in range(start + 1, len(s) + 1):
    prefix = s[start:i]
    if isind(prefix):
      # We used the whole thing, but it's a word!
      if i == len(s):
        return [prefix]
      words = getwords(s, i)
      if words:
        return [prefix] + words

  # We made it to the end without finding a word configuration
  return False
```

A DP algorithm is documented [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-32-word-break-problem/), and in the book "Elements of Programming Interviews".  My question is: ***Why?***

I cannot find any instance where my non-DP solution is re-computing the same subproblems.  Can anyone explain why this algorithm is inferior to the DP algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. (adverbqqqqqqqqqqq)
2. ad,verb,(qqqqqqqqqqq)
3. adverb,(qqqqqqqqqqq)

There will be two getwords('adverbqqqqqqqqqqq', 6) calls, no?

And it'll get really nasty if you have something like:

adverbhamstringadverbhamstring...adverbhamstringhorsepowerqqq

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The best way to show someone wrong is always to produce a pathological case.  I appreciate it!

Comment: That is a very pleasant and gracious response. *tips hat*

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it, if you have a word `w` with `n` letters, and there are `k` valid word combinations in `w[0:n-1]` (i.e. `w[0:n-1]` can be split into valid words, in different places, `k` times), you will look for `w[n]` in the dictionary `k` times (assuming `w[n]` is not a valid word, of course). This is what ozangds showed in his answer.

With the dynamic programming approach, since you only keep track of the index before which the string is valid (can be split into words), you will only look for `w(n)` one time.

Look for TulsiRam's and geekyandgirly's comments in the link you posted, they help understand both sides of the problem.